# Merge data from two large list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a two lists of dictionaries. List A has 50K elements, list B has 500 elements.
I need to merge data from the lists.
What I use now is a simple straightforward solution:

```
for element_a in a:
    for element_b in b:
        if element_a.get('key') == element_a.get('key'):
            element_a.get('value') = element_b.get('value')
```

But this solution seems very slow. Any ideas how to re-write the code above?

**EDIT:** A possible solution might be sorting each list by the `key` value, but are there any other "more pretty" solutions?

Comment: can you show how your 2 lists look like?

Comment: Do you actually have to run this more than once? If so, consider to use a proper backend such as a database or `pandas`. If not, consider https://xkcd.com/1205/.

Comment: Can you give a sample of how your dictionaries inside the lists look like. and your merge criteria seems to be based on 'key' value.. what happens an item from list-a is not having any matching key in list-b?? and you are just assigning one value here.. is that all you want to do.. edit the question to be a bit more clearer..

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import random

d1 = {}  
d2 = {}

def gen():
    for i in range(50000):
        d1['key'+str(i)] = 'value' + str(i)
    for i in range(500):
        rnd_index = random.randint(1,50000)
        d2['key'+str(rnd_index)] = 'value' + str(i)

def run():
    start_time = time.time()
    concat = [d1, d2]
    keys = set().union(d1.keys(), d2.keys())
    target = {}
    for key in keys:
      target[key] = list( target[key] for target in concat if key in target)
    print(f"{(time.time() - start_time)} seconds")

gen()
run()

# around 0.06582760810852051 seconds
```

For example, input:

```
d1 = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val3'}  
d2 = {'key1': 'val2', 'key2': 'val4', 'key3': 'val5'}
```

output:

```
{'key1': ['val1', 'val2'], 'key3': ['val5'], 'key2': ['val3', 'val4']}
```